# Is setting a value attribute in TextInput necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I was having issues with something like this (specifically in the `TextInput` value attribute):

```
const Stuff = props => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const handleNewItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, '']);
  };

  const handleText = (text, index) => {
    items[index] = text;
    setItems(items);
    // this was populating correctly in console.log
    // as I type, it will come out like ["somedata", "blah"....] etc...
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
        <View>
          {items.map((items, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={index}>
                <Text>{index + 1}</Text>

                // issue with setting value attribute
                // Text would disappear as I type in the input field
                <TextInput value={items} onChangeText={text => handleText(text, index)} />

              </View>
            );
          })}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={e => handleNewItem(e)}>
            <Text>Add item</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

I was able to get console logged out the correct values for `items`, but on my mobile simulator, when I type something, the text disappears.

When I removed `value={items}` from the TextInput component, I'm able to type in the simulator input field, without the text disappearing. I always thought we needed a value from reactjs. Do we not need this? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest don't directly update your state. Instead use new object to update the state like

```js
  const handleText = (text, index) => {
    let newItems = [...items];
    newItems[index] = text;
    setItems(newItems);
  };
```

Comment: is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't think so. didn't really answer my main question in this post =\

Comment: Well setting a value attribute in textinput is recommended. Otherwise it will behave like uncontrolled component. That may lose its state.